# Write a `\tag` in math display mode such that it won't automatically be enclosed by parentheses and such that Overleaf won't complain

Tags: tags

How can I write a `\tag` in math display mode such that it won't automatically be enclosed by parentheses and such that Overleaf won't complain? (I presume that it's bad practice to ignore Overleaf's complaints.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

The following would be perfect if the automatic parentheses enclosing the tag were removed:

\[J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1 \tag{for $m \geqq 0$ and $0 \leqq l < 2^m$}\]

The following output is good

\[J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1 \tag*{for $m \geqq 0$ and $0 \leqq l < 2^m$}\]

yet Overleaf complains about it; in particular, it introduces a red warning dot in the margin of the Code Editor, whose drop-down text reads:

\begin{verbatim}
unclosed open display math \[ found at $
unclosed open group { found at $
unexpected $ after open group {
unexpected $ after open display math \[
unexpected $ after open display math \[
unexpected $ after open display math \[
unexpected $ after open display math \[
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't something like `\begin{equation*}
J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1 \qquad \text{for $m \geqq 0$ and $0 \leqq l < 2^m$}
\end{equation*}` make more sense than abusing tags?

Comment: .... that being said, I don't get an error from your code, neither with overleaf nor with an up to date texlive2023

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz What you propose is a good alternative, thanks. Is there a way to do something like it but have the comment be flush right?

Comment: If Overleaf is unable to cope with a legal LaTeX construction, then it's an Overleaf problem. This said, you shouldn't have the condition flush right, because it's part of the equation.

Comment: I get a red warning dot on the TeX side of things.  The part you need to pay attention to is the red number of errors that appears next to "Recompile".  In this case, there are no errors, so you don't need to worry about the warning dot.  But as others have pointed out, it's better to use `\text` than `\tag`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not good that Overleaf rejects a perfectly legal LaTeX construct. On the other hand, you shouldn't abuse tags for such cases, because the condition is part of the equation, while tags aren't.

Anyway, you can keep Overleaf quiet, using `\ttag` defined by

```
\newcommand{\ttag}{\tag*}
```

Avoid blank lines before displays, they're wrong. A blank line can follow a display, if the next text starts a new paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\newcommand{\ttag}{\tag*}

\begin{document}

The following would be perfect if the automatic parentheses enclosing the tag were removed:
\[
J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1 
\tag{for $m \geqq 0$ and $0 \leqq l < 2^m$}
\]
The following output is good
\[
J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1 
\ttag{for $m \geqq 0$ and $0 \leqq l < 2^m$}
\]
But this output is much better
\[
J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1, 
\qquad\text{for $m \geqq 0$ and $0 \leqq l < 2^m$}
\]
as you can clearly see, because the conditions are part of the equation.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The Overleaf window shows no red dot.

[image]